# pandas: taking corresponding differences

Tags: python, pandas

I have two D`ataFrame`s, one of which is larger than the other (A). The labels on B are all contained within A. I want to take the difference (A-B) for the row/column values that correspond. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply do A.sub(B). For example:

```
df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), columns=['one','two'])
A = df.ix[1:, ['one', 'two']]
B = df.ix[:2, ['one']].apply(lambda x: x *2)
```

If A is:

```
     one        two
1   -0.999523   -2.111082
2   -2.197760   -0.412689
3   -0.534728    0.037255
```

and B is:

```
    one
0   -1.940326
1   -1.999046
2   -4.395521
```

A.sub(B) will give you:

```
     one        two
0    NaN        NaN
1    0.999523   NaN
2    2.197760   NaN
3    NaN        NaN
```

Or have I misunderstood the question?